# error message disappears too fast in jquery validation engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using JQuery Validation engine to validate two values and display a message . But error disappear fast.

***I want the error message to stay visible on focus out until validation succeed.***

```
<input class="form-control validate[required,custom[number]] text-input" value="0" type="text" id="eRoomFrom"  />

<input class="form-control validate[required,custom[number]] text-input" value="0" type="text" id="eRoomTo"  />
```

here Is my jquery code:

```
$("#eRoomTo").change(function () {
        var s1=$("#eRoomFrom").val();
        var s2=$("#eRoomTo").val();
        var s3=s2-s1+1;
        //    alert(s3);
        $("#eTotalRooms").val(s3);
        if(s1>s2){

            $('#eRoomTo').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Rooms From Should be less then Rooms To', 'fail', 'topRight', true)     
        }
        else
        {
            $(".gradeX").remove();
            $('#eRoomTo').validationEngine('hide');
        }
    });



    $("#eRoomFrom").change(function () {

        var s1=$("#eRoomFrom").val();
        var s2=$("#eRoomTo").val();
        if(s2!=""){
            if(s1>s2)
                $('#eRoomTo').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Rooms From Should be less then Rooms To', 'fail', 'topRight', true)
        }
        else{
            $('#eRoomTo').validationEngine('hide');
            $(".gradeX").remove();
        }
    });
```